# What is a baseline function in policy gradients methods?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is this same as the Advantage Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A baseline function can be any function that doesn't affect the *expected* policy gradient update. Generally any function that does not *directly* depend on the current action choice or parametric policy function.

The idea for choosing a "good" baseline is to choose something that can correct for variance due to using the *raw* policy gradient for updates.

You actually have a lot of choices for the baseline function. Typical choices are $\bar{R}$, the average reward, or $V(s)$ the state value function (which can then lead to Actor-Critic methods, if you use it further to calculate a TD error for correcting the policy on each step).

> Is this same as the Advantage Function?

The Advantage function can be treated as a baseline-already-included estimate, because it is $Q_{\pi}(s,a) - V_{\pi}(s)$. By using $A(s,a)$ as the gradient multiplier for policy gradient update steps, you are implictly using policy gradients with $V(s)$ as the baseline.

You might be able to use the Advantage function in some other way to establish a different baseline. However, you should not use the current policy to decide the action in $A(s,a)$ if you do so, because that is not independent of the policy gradient. You could use e.g. $\text{max}_a A(s,a)$ - I am not sure how well that would work in practice, but I think it would be a valid baseline function.